# libcouchbase not instaling on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6

Tags: linux, couchbase, redhat

Following the [documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/c-sdk/2.10/sdk-release-notes.html) for RHEL/CentOS, this is how I try to install libcouchbase:

```sh
wget http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/couchbase-release/couchbase-release-1.0-6-x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -iv couchbase-release-1.0-6-x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install libcouchbase-devel libcouchbase2-bin gcc gcc-c++
```

However `libcouchbase-devel` and `libcouchbase2-bin` fail with:

```
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libcouchbase.so.2.0.65 conflicts between attempted installs of libcouchbase-2.10.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64 and libcouchbase2-core-2.10.3-1.el6.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

I tried installing those packages one at a time but, if I install `libcouchbase-devel` first it succeeds and `libcouchbase2-bin` fail. If I remove what I installed and do `libcouchbase2-bin first it succeeds, but then`libcouchbase-devel` fails.

This clearly points to a conflict somewhere, but I am unsure what this conflict is exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all packages that have couchbase in their name: `yum remove packagename`

Then, `yum install libcouchbase libcouchbase-devel`